# Pacemaker Virtual IP is still pinging

Tags: cluster, pacemaker

I am having two node pacemaker cluster, with one virtual IP which is 192.168.3.100.

The virtual ip is the part of cluster resource, when I stop the cluster using pcs cluster stop --all.

I am still able to ping the virtual ip i.e. 192.168.3.100.

I believe the VIP should not ping if cluster services and it's resources are down, or am I doing something wrong here.

Please advice.

Comment: Answering my own question....

Answer (score 0):

After going through my own cluster configuration, I found that my VIP was not getting flushed from routing table of server.

There was a custom script added in the resources of pacemaker cluster which was adding the VIP routing entries in the system, as it was the requirement but when we were bringing down the cluster, the script was not flushing the routing table entry of VIP.

After modifying the script it is now working and VIP is not pinging even after the cluster is down.

We can also delete the routing table entry manually using ip route command after bringing down the cluster.

Hope this save's someone's day.